# Remove Google Maps Hyperlinks from Addresses, Contacts and Accounts

Tags: contact, fields, google, hyperlink

We have a request to remove all Google Maps hyperlinks on our addresses, so that users can copy addresses more easily. Is there a way to remove these hyperlinks? I've already turned of Google Maps integration in the Maps/Locations part of the system.

Thanks!

Laura

[image]

Comment: Why not have a formula field that will display the address in plain text? Then your users can copy from that field.

Comment: Ideally we would only have the address listed once... our users can get easily confused. Is there any way to just turn off this link?

Comment: How are these links being created? Have you got some kind of AppExchange package that is doing this for you?